# iCloud Photo Library

Tags: safari

If I press the 'disable and delete ' button will my photos come back onto my phone or go somewhere else ? Where will they go and is there any way I can get them back into my photo library ?[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have those 1060 photos in your phone, and they are only on your iCloud, then if you press the 'disable and delete ' button then those photos and videos won't come to your iPhone automatically. You will have to manually download those photos from iCloud, then copy them to your iPhone using iTunes. If you do not download them from iCloud within 30 days, then they will be deleted forever from iCloud, and you can never get them back

Answer (score 0):

If you disable and delete the iCloud Photo Library from your phone, all your photos will all be available on iCloud.
As stated, you will have 30 days to download them from there.

Comment: I think the OP wants to know *how* (s)he can download them.